# different install Targets with cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a project consisting of three binaries and two libraries. Today I have 2 CMakeLists.txt files for each part, because I want `make install` to copy the compiled files to the project/bin directory for development and for production use I want it to install the files to `/usr/`...

I would like to have a separate `make install-dev` and `make install` or something like that. Is that possible with cmake? I searched in the cmake docs but found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know of to move the install point is to use relative paths for your install directories

```
install(TARGETS t tlib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)
```

and then when you run cmake for development run it like this

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/projhome/bin
```

for release like this

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
```